# CSS broken on upload

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I built a site based off a bootstrap template. 
I linked to my own CSS to add my own design touches.
It works in dreamweaver, but when uploaded to the hosting site, the css breaks. 
The bootstrap CSS links fine, however my added CSS won't load or apply correctly.

I'm kind of a noob, there may be some very simple thing I'm overlooking.

http://mhatlaw.com/index.html

Comment: The file `http://mhatlaw.com/css/added.css` won't load because of a permissions error (403); does that help?

Comment: All these haven't been loaded:
added.css (Forbidden),
ie-emulation-modes-warning.js (Not Found),
2ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js (Not Found), 
ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css (Not Found)

Comment: It looks like your publish method missed the css file.  How are you publishing/uploading?  Ftp?

Comment: I was publishing via dreamweaver. I manually uploaded the css file on the host and it worked.

Comment: Well, the files /css/added.css and /bootstrap/docs/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js work now, but /assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css is still missing. And the favicon.